# Any feedback or advice on multiplayer platform for Android games?

Tags: android, multiplayer

I'd like to add multiplayer mode for an Android game (a turn by turn game).
So I'm looking for a multiplayer platform.
The most important feature I'm waiting for such a platform is to let users do some matches against random users on the Internet.
Casmul looks good, but it looks a little bit heavy (maybe too many features for what I want?).

Do you have some feedback with that kind of platform. Any advice ?

Regards,

Comment: when you say android?  Unity works for multiplayer.

Comment: Unity is now free for Android: http://unity3d.com/unity/multiplatform/mobile